# Why is function `bracket` called bracket in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Why is the `bracket` function called bracket?

I assume it has to do with the **type signature** syntax; brackets are used in the type signature to denote a function. Lets see the type signature of function map:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

The first parameter of map is a function.

Now, let's have a look at `bracket` on Hackage.

```
bracket:: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> (a -> IO c)  -> IO c
```

Bracket:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:bracket

Okay I get it, the parameters of bracket are functions with IO actions.

Examples on Hackage use `bracket` like this:

```
bracket
  (openFile "filename" ReadMode)
  (hClose)
  (\fileHandle -> do { ... })
```

After contemplating for a while I considered the name "bracket" not favorable.

I would say "performResourceSafely" would be a better fit.

So I ask again: Why is the `bracket` function called bracket?

Comment: My guess is that the name is chosen because it encloses a resource. Haskell developers often prefer short names to long "javaish" names.

Comment: Makes sense to me. Brackets set the "ends" of something (a beginning and an end), and group a contained unit together. That's happening with this function by setting what happens at the start and end of execution. The first two arguments bracket the third.

Comment: `performResourceSafely` doesn't accurately describe what it does since it's a much more general function than that.

Comment: "Bracket" is really just a synonym for "surround".

Comment: @chepner  @Carcigenicate  In Haskell tuples are defined with brackets. So giving a function the name "bracket" may indicate some correlation with tuples, but `bracket` doesn't have anything to do with tuples.

Comment: That's a regional problem. In American English, "bracket" refers to `[`/`]`, not `(`/`)`. A function name would use the word "tuple" explicitly, not indirectly refer to a tuple by the syntactic element used to define such a value.

Comment: I'm grasping at straws here but, looking in the Haskell Report, a comment about the function `withForeignPtr :: ForeignPtr a -> (Ptr a -> IO b) -> IO b` says "All uses of the pointer should be inside the withForeignPtr *bracket*". So maybe the name `bracket` comes from the fact that you need to use brackets for writing the callback in the signature? https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch29.html#x37-28000029

Comment: We're in Monadland, so it's a doo-hickey in Category Theory, for example nice diagram here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143861/naturality-of-the-lie-bracket". See 'Lie Bracket', 'Poisson Bracket', 'Dirac Bracket', ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **bracket** v. To bound on both sides, to surround, as enclosing with brackets
>     — [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bracket#Verb)

The thing that `bracket` does is it wraps some operation that uses a resource with the actions that allocate and deallocate that resource (with some care taken to ensure that deallocation happens even when exceptions are thrown). So the (de)allocation actions surround – or *bracket* – the main operation.

The file example you mention is especially suggestive. Like "open bracket" for `[` or `(` and "close bracket" for `]` or `)`, the bracketing actions are "open file" and "close file" (well, "close handle"). This parallel is fairly common; e.g. with databases, one opens and closes a connection, with network stuff, one opens and closes a session, with subprocesses, one opens and closes a program, etc.

Comment: So when you use `bracket` you are saying "Bracket target computation given on argument #3 with computations given on argument #1 and #2".

Comment: @Julian Exactly.